# How to make MSYS2 pacman believe I installed a package?

Tags: mingw, msys

I am using MinGW-w64 and MSYS2 on Windows 10. Suppose that there are two libraries A and B. B depends on A, but it also depends on a lot of other things. The official version of library A has a few bugs on Windows, which I fixed by manually downloading the source, patching the source, and compiling. Now when I want to install library B through pacman, it tells me library A is not installed, and will re-install it. How to make pacman believe I really installed library A?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out! The pacman has an option to disable certain dependency check. It's `--assume-installed (pkg name of library A)=(version of library)`.